# Waiting for connectivity with react-scripts on ionic serve

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, react-scripts

I have an Ionic project, which works fine on my windows machine and friend's mac, but I got a problem on linux.

The problem appears on `ionic serve`, it's infinitely `Waiting for connectivity with react-scripts...`, and appearing continues while it's running. Development server seems to work fine.

Hope, we'll find a solution.

CLI output:

```
npm run start

> [project name]@0.0.1 start
> ionic serve

> react-scripts start
[react-scripts] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.66/
[react-scripts] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
[react-scripts] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /[project path]/app/public
[react-scripts] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
[react-scripts] Starting the development server...
[react-scripts] 
[react-scripts] You can now view better-call in the browser.
[react-scripts]   Local:            http://localhost:8100
[react-scripts]   On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.66:8100
[react-scripts] Note that the development build is not optimized.
[react-scripts] To create a production build, use npm run build.
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with react-scripts...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with react-scripts...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with react-scripts...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with react-scripts...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with react-scripts...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with react-scripts...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with react-scripts...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with react-scripts...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with react-scripts...
```

Comment: @owl11 Did you ever resolve this? I'm having this same issue right now. Everything was fine when I was l last working on this project.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue, because I used node 18, with 16 it's better.
You can resolve it with this:

1. Install npm i n.
2. Install older version of node, 16 works fine for me, then install it with this command -> n 16.
3. Change version of node that you want, just put n in your terminal, and then select the 16 node version, and use ionic serve again

I hope this works for you.

Best

Comment: not working with node v16.19.0.